# How do I repeat an update statement from one table to another with same code values?

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2012

I am using Microsoft SQL server management studio with excel spreadsheets

I have 2 tables extracted from 2 separate spreadsheets.

One table (StockList) has data from my supplier with 5600 lines of products that I can extract daily, with

```
    ProductCode VARCHAR(40),
    Brand VARCHAR(40),
    ProductDescription VARCHAR(300),
    UnitPrice VARCHAR(40),
    CTNPrice VARCHAR(40)
```

The other table (MasterSheet) is my current order list with 600 lines of products with

```
     Code VARCHAR(40),
     Item VARCHAR(40),
     Unit VARCHAR(10),
     Price VARCHAR(10),
     PerPack VARCHAR(10),
     PackSize VARCHAR(10)
```

As prices change from my supplier, but the code remains the same what I want to do is automatically update the price on the [MasterSheet] table from the [StockList] table by reference of the code. The following statement updates one of the codes at a time

```
     UPDATE MasterSheet
     set price = (select UnitPrice from StockList where ProductCode = '38074')
     from StockList
     where code = '38074'
```

which works perfectly but I wanted to know if you could update all the codes at the same time with one statement rather than creating hundreds of update statements. I am only wanting to update the [price] from [StockList] nothing else.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the two tables to update all the records at once.

```
UPDATE MS SET
    Price = SL.UnitPrice
FROM MasterSheet MS
    INNER JOIN StockList SL
        ON MS.Code = SL.ProductCode
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your logic using a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE MasterSheet ms
     set price = (select UnitPrice from StockList sl where sl.ProductCode = ms.Code);
```

Your original query does not look correctly written.  It is simpler as:

```
 UPDATE MasterSheet
     set price = (select UnitPrice from StockList where ProductCode = '38074');
     where code = '38074';
```

Note the remove of the `from` clause.

The use of `from StockList` just means that the same update is repeated thousands of times -- once for each row in `StockList`.